# What does the vector whose components are products of components of two vectors represent?

Tags: geometry, vectors

Say there are two vector $\vec a$ and $\vec b$ with:

$\vec a = a_1 \mathbf i + a_2 \mathbf j + a_3 \mathbf k + ...$, and

$\vec b = b_1 \mathbf i + b_2 \mathbf j + b_3 \mathbf k + ...$

What does the vector $\vec c = a_1b_1 \mathbf i + a_2b_2 \mathbf j + a_3b_3 \mathbf k + ...$ represent?

Is there a geometric interpretation of this vector $\vec c$ in relation to the two original vectors $\vec a$ and $\vec b$?

Comment: No. Look at the products of different pairs of parallel and perpendicular vectors and you'll see the behavior of this "component-product" wildly varies. This is a reflection of the fact that it is not invariant under a (SO(3)) change of basis, unlike the standard dot product or cross-product.